# Нужна помощь с ботом VK

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, бот

Извиняюсь, за, возможно, глупый вопрос, только начал изучать vk api и php. Хочу сделать vk бота, который получает логин и пароль от, например, StackOverFlow и оповещает о наличии новых сообщений, только не знаю как реализовать безопасную авторизацию. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Новых сообщений где ? на сайте ? в вк ?

Comment: о сообщениях на сайте.

Comment: не совсем понял, о каком логине - пароле идет речь..создайте на сервере cron задачу, в которой пропишите, чтобы шла проверка на непрочитанные сообщения. Если таковы имеются, достаете ID пользователя (вк) и сам текст непрочитанного сообщения, а оттуда уже отправляете извещение с нужными данными непосредственно пользователю в ВК. `ВАЖНО`, чтобы пользователь состоял в группе и не блокировал ранее сообщения от группы.